# Custom elements: when to set up event listeners

Tags: custom-element

The custom elements specification lists ["Requirements for custom element constructors"](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/custom-elements.html#custom-element-conformance).

Herein, the last advisory statement is

> In general, the constructor should be used to set up initial state and default values, **and to set up event listeners** and possibly a shadow root.

Now, regarding the life cycle of web components, removing a custom element from the DOM calls the `disconnectedCallback` lifecycle hook. To my understanding, this would be **the point in time where I remove any event listeners added by the custom element**.

Now, if I still hold a reference to that element, and at a later point, I put it back in the DOM, this will trigger the `connectedCallback` lifecycle hook.

And here's my problem: If it is advised to set up event listeners in the `constructor` rather than (properly guarded) in the `connectedCallback`, the re-introduced custom element will not receive its listeners, which were previously cleaned up by the `disconnectedCallback`.

I feel the *add event listeners in the constructor* advice - which I quoted from the spec - doesn't really go well together with the designed life cycle.

Are custom elements simply not meant to be removed *from* and later, reintroduced *into* the DOM?

Does anyone have reference as of how this is meant to be tackled? Is there some sort of best practice regarding the attaching and removing of listeners?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tend to put my `addEventListener` calls in `connectedCallback`. Why do them before? The control is not in the DOM and you can not interact with it.

I also put my `removeEventListeners` in `disconnectedCallback`. Sometimes I might even, when the internal DOM is complex, clear the internal DOM.

There are a few components where I add `addEventListener` into the constructor, but:

1. Only if it is for shadowDOM
2. Only if I do not care to remove them myself since they will get cleaned up automatically when the internal DOM is destroyed by garbage collection.
3. When I am just writing a simple test component

But this is not something I do often. If there is *any* chance that my component might be added to and removed from the DOM, then I feel it must happen in `connectedCallback` and `disconnectedCallback`.